# Заполнение DаtaGrid в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c#, многопоточность, datagridview

Здравствуйте. Решил оптимизировать свою программу, которая заполняла DаtaGrid разными потоками построчно.
Теперь каждый поток заполняет свои столбцы, а другие потоки их построчно анализируют. Столкнулся с проблемами при отладке, когда приложение виснет с ошибкой

> Ошибка: При определении функции ' функция ' Истекло время ожидания и необходимости прерывается небезопасным способом

Собственно вопрос: Как все это сделать потокобезопасно, организовать запись в DаtaGrid/DataTable несколькими потоками(каждый поток заполняет только свои столбцы) и в результате иметь возможность нормально отладить программу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте перед записью блокировать ваш DataGrid используя lock().
Таким образом каждый ваш поток будет ждать пока другой освободит DataGrid и проблем не будет.

Пример:

```
lock (dataGrid)
{
    //Тут какие то действия с DataGrid
}
```

P.S. Лучше сначала заполнять данные в отдельный объект, а потом один раз их выводить, чем с нескольких потоков заполнять ячейки одного DataGrid.

Comment: Локированием не поможет в моем случае, т.к. один поток очень шустрый и заполняет сразу по сто столбцов. другие потоки его будут вечно ждать. А вот отдельный объект и синхронизация в едином потоке отличная идея) есть ли какие то специфические функции синхронизации/обновления datatable?

Comment: @Александр: Если вы используете WPF то вы можете сделать обычный Binding к ItemsSource и при обновлении коллекции он будет сам отлавливать добавленные элементы.
А вообще независимо от типа контрола вы можете один раз устанавливать этот объект в DataSource.